# How to properly pass data to fragment using external AsyncTask and Interface callback

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I had this setup working when I just had an activity but now when im trying to use it in a fragment Im a little bit confused,  Im not sure if i need to implement the interface and override the methods in the fragment or leave it in the activity and somehow pass the data to fragment from activity.

**Interface**

```
    public interface TaskListener{
    void onTaskFinish(String m);
}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{
private TaskListener taskListener;
Activity activity;
int type;
String gid;
int result = -1;
String gameName;

public DatabaseOperations(int type, Activity activity, String gid){
    this.type = type;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.gid = gid;
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params){
    if(type == 1){
        gameName = getGameName(gid);
        result = 1;
    }
    if(type ==2){
        //other database function
        result = 2;
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){
    if(result == 1){
        taskListener.onTaskFinish(gameName);        
    }
    if(result ==2){
        //other return
    }

    super.onPostExecute(s);
}

public String getGameName(String gameId){
    //insert database function here
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no hard guideline on this, but generally, I believe that it is more common (and safer) to have the Activity communicate with your 'service' (AsyncTask), and then communicate the result to the Fragment.

To communicate with the fragment, you can either implement interfaces in the Activity and the Fragment that define how they communicate, or you can employ a message bus.

Also, be aware that despite being in the API and being shown in lots of examples, AsyncTask has some non-obvious, non-trivial issues, and I personally recommend staying away from them completely. Without you doing a lot of work on your own, your AsyncTask is not going to be synchronized with the Activity lifecycle. For instance, what happens if the user rotates the device or navigates to a different activity while your AsyncTask is still in it's doInBackground method?

I personally prefer using RxJava to handle background tasks, but there are other solutions to this problem as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice I will look into that method and I will also take a look at RxJava

Comment: would it be bad if i did something like this?

Comment: //MainActivity

@Override
public void onTaskFinish(String result){
 MyFragment mf = 
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");
 if(mf != null){
  mf.setResult(result);
 }
    }



    //in fragment

    String result;

    public void setResult(String result){
 this.result = result;
}

Answer (score 0):

**Inside AsyncTask:**

```
public TaskListener delegate = null;

.......

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        delegate.onTaskFinish(result);

    }
```

**Inside Fragment:**

```
    public class YourFragment implements TaskListener
    {

    .......

    //execute as per your requirement
    MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask (type, activity, gid);
         myAsyncTask.delegate = (AsyncResponse) this;
         myAsyncTask.execute();

    ......

    //implement method

     @Override
        public void onTaskFinish(String output) {
            parseResult(output);
        }

}
```

Comment: So it is better to implement the interface in the fragment and override the method there

Comment: Yes. As per your requirement, it is better.

Comment: "myAsyncTask.delegate = (AsyncResponse) this;"  on this part you need to pass activity for this to work, how do i get the reference to the fragement so that when i call the onTaskFinish it knows to execute the overriden method in the fragment and not the overriden method in the main activity